# Why does the associated sheaf vanish?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I am learning local cohomology from Hartshorne’s book Local Cohomology.
My question is about understanding a line in the proof of proposition 1.11 in this book.
The set-up for proposition 1.11 is that a topological space $X$, a closed subset $Y$ of $X$ and an abelian sheaf $F$ are given, and that $V=X-Y$, $n$ is an integer.
Proposition 1.11 states that conditions (1) and (2) are equivalent:
(1) For all $i\leq n$, $\underline{H^i_Y}(F)=0$.
(2) For all open subsets $U$ of $X$,the map $\alpha_i:H^i(U,F)\rightarrow H^i(U\cap V,F)$ is injective for $i=0$, and an isomorphism for all $i<n$.
My question is about a line in the proof of (2) implies (1), which states that “But the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U\rightarrow H^n(U,F)$ is zero, since $n>0$.”
I don’t see why this statement is true.
Could someone please explain why this statement holds? Thank you so much for your kind help.

Comment: Your functors (sheafification of cohomology, in all degrees) form a universal delta functor from the category of sheaves on X to itself, and so is the system consisting of identity in degree zero and zero in positive degrees. More generally, for a map from X to Y, sheafifying cohomology of F on preimages of opens on Y computes the higher direct images.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind guidance. Your explanations, including the generalization to a map of topological spaces, are very insightful. I understand the reasoning now.